# Unity add second PersistentListener not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create a custom editor that automatically creates gameobject, their components and automatically adding the listeners to the events.

but adding two persistent listener to the events does not work, but if i separate it, it will work.

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Create Animation/With SFX", false, -1)]
static void CreateAnimationWithSFX()
{
    GameObject go = new GameObject("animationWithSFX");
    go.transform.SetParent(Selection.activeTransform);

    AudioSource audioSource = go.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
    AudioMixer mixer = Resources.Load("Master") as AudioMixer;
    audioSource.outputAudioMixerGroup = mixer.FindMatchingGroups("SFX")[0];

    SceneAnimationEvent script = go.AddComponent<SceneAnimationEvent>();

    // audioSource.Play
    script.Events = new UnityEvent();
    UnityAction methodDelegate = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof(UnityAction), audioSource, "Play") as UnityAction;
    UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener (script.Events, methodDelegate);

    // animator.Play(string) - its only add this animator
    script.Events = new UnityEvent();
    UnityAction<string> methodDelegateString = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityAction<string>), Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponent<Animator>(), "Play") as UnityAction<string>;
    UnityEventTools.AddStringPersistentListener(script.Events, methodDelegateString, "lala");

    Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(go, "Create " + go.name);
    Selection.activeObject = go;
}
```

I believe the first element of the unityevent is being overwrite, because if i comment adding persistent listener for animator , the audio play will work.

[image]

Comment: By now, I would think you know that adding the language tag is very important.

Comment: You are setting the `Events` property on `Script` twice. Set it once, then add all your listeners to the `Events` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    // audioSource.Play
    script.Events = new UnityEvent();
    UnityAction methodDelegate = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof(UnityAction), audioSource, "Play") as UnityAction;
    UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener (script.Events, methodDelegate);

    // animator.Play(string) - its only add this animator
    script.Events = new UnityEvent();
    UnityAction<string> methodDelegateString = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityAction<string>), Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponent<Animator>(), "Play") as UnityAction<string>;
    UnityEventTools.AddStringPersistentListener(script.Events, methodDelegateString, "lala");
```

I'd hazard a guess that this is the issue:

```
 script.Events = new UnityEvent();
```

You are doing this twice - once at the start, then once you've added an event listener to the `Events` object, you are calling the above code again.

The above code will replace the original instance with a brand new `UnityEvent()` object instance that doesn't have any attached event handlers. You then attach an event handler to it - hence the reason only one works.

Try this instead:

```
    script.Events = new UnityEvent(); // Only create the UnityEvent instance once
    UnityAction methodDelegate = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof(UnityAction), audioSource, "Play") as UnityAction;
    UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener (script.Events, methodDelegate);

    UnityAction<string> methodDelegateString = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityAction<string>), Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponent<Animator>(), "Play") as UnityAction<string>;
    UnityEventTools.AddStringPersistentListener(script.Events, methodDelegateString, "lala");
```

Dislcaimer: I've never used Unity before - there could be another way to add multiple event handlers to a script.